# Watir-webdriver: Firefox not clicking correct link but IE and Chrome working fine

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir, browser-automation, watir-webdriver

Question help

Hi I'm new to Ruby and watir-webdriver and I've searched all over and can't find an answer to this.

I have a link that is inside a table, this table has a header on top of the table that sorts the table numerically if clicked. In Chrome and Ie, the link is clicked fine and continues on but in firefox it clicks the header and reorganizes the table, but not the link and no error message is given.

I've tried xpath, regexp, table referencing, :href, :text, (there are no id or name fields), and using the .flash method I've seen that it looks at the correct link, but still clicks the top of the table.

Here is the html

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="0" class="canclick" width="14%" align="left" datatype="string">
            Contract #
            <span id="sortIndicatorBlank">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="backD">
        <td width="10%" valign="top" align="left">
             <a href="/policy/clientAccountSummary.action?forwarder=ClientList&basho.menuNodeId=12801&basho.taskPanelNodeId=1261&number=015633828"> 015633828 </a>
        </td>
```

Here is the code I'm using that clicks the correct link in Chrome and Ie but not in firefox

```
link = "015633828"

exp1 = Regexp.new link

@browser.link(:href, exp1).click
```

Again to clarify: Using .flash method it finds the correct link(flashes the link I want to click inside the table), but on the actual .click operation it clicks the "Contract #" portion of the header not the link.

I think the problem might be that the table header, is a floating header, ie it moves with you as you scroll down the page and stays at the top of the page so that its always visible.

If you need more info to clarify let me know. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know a header is clicked, and not the link? Especially if flash flashes the link, but they click clicks the header.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem just with the HTML you have provided here? I think there is no way that Firefox will click a header if you tell it to click the link.

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure if that was actually possible. I'm going off of just watching the browser as it runs through the test. It gets to the site, scrolls down until the link is at the top of the page, then the table reorganizes itself as if the header was clicked, then goes on to the next step as if it clicked the link correctly.

Comment: Also, if I try it on the same type of table, but with a smaller amount of information in it where all of it will fit on the screen it will click the link just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why it is doing this, but as a potential workaround could you perhaps try something along the following lines to pull the href value out of the link and then have the browser goto it directly?

```
@browser.goto(@browser.link(:text, ' 015633828 ').href)
```

(you might need to add the base url for the site to the href to make that work, but you get the idea)

Comment: Yea that work around worked.

Wouldn't mind finding out if there was a way to get it to work with the floating header in case I run into this problem again. Thanks for everyone's answers/help though!

Answer (score 1):

or possibly try with xpath:

@browser.link(:xpath,"//a[@text='*someUser#*']").click

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to make sure a link inside `td` tag is clicked, and not a link inside `th` tag, try this:

```
browser.td.link(:href => /someUser#/).click
```

It is a good thing that you have provided both HTML and Watir code, but in the future, try to provide real HTML (or as real as possible). `someUser#` really confused me, I am not even sure I understood the problem.

If the solution I have provided does not work, please edit the question to contain real HTML.

Comment: I edited the post to contain the real html. The solution you provided still clicked the header.

Comment: I think that firefox is scrolling down until the link is at the top of the page, but doing that makes the floating header cover up the link and then it clicks the header. (Hopefully that makes sense)

Is there a way to lock the scroll bar?